# Get row indices based on condition in Spark

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

Let's say I have a Spark DataFrame as shown below. How can I get the row indices where `value` is 0?

```
ID  | value
-------------
001 | 1
002 | 0
003 | 2
004 | 0
005 | 1
```

Row indices I want are 2 and 4.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `filter` and `select` to get the indexes you want as

Given a `dataframe` as

```
+---+-----+
|ID |value|
+---+-----+
|001|1    |
|002|0    |
|003|2    |
|004|0    |
|005|1    |
+---+-----+
```

you can do the following

```
df.filter(df.value == 0).select(df.ID)
```

which should give you

```
+---+
|ID |
+---+
|002|
|004|
+---+
```

you can use `.flatMap(lambda x: x).collect()` to convert the above selected column `dataframe` to `list`

I hope the answer is helpful

Answer (score 0):

There is no such thing as indices in Spark `DataFrame`. Same as SQL tables, `DataFrame` is unordered, unless sorted specifically.

There is a `row_number` window function, but it is not intended for global orderings.

Overall, if you think about the order, you probably approach Spark from the wrong direction.

Answer (score 0):

There are ways you can do this, I'm thinking rdd.zipwithindex() and filtering. But why do you need to do this? Attempting to use row indices is generally discouraged--what is the eventual goal you are attempting to accomplish with these indices? There might be a better way of doing this.

Answer (score -1):

```
val index = ss.sparkContext
    .parallelize(Seq((1,1), (2,0), (3,2), (4,0), (5,1)))
    .toDF("ID", "value")

index.where($"value" === 0).select("ID").show()
```

Comment: Usually it's better to explain a solution instead of just posting some rows of anonymous code. You can read [How do I write a good answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer), and also [Explaining entirely code-based answers](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-%E2%80%8C%E2%80%8Bcode-based-answers).